# Unexpected result from query based on old column value

Tags: mysql

I need to update a column and based on the old value, update a second column.

After googling I came up with [THIS (*nr 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/559291/1685196) solution: copy the table to have the old value at hand.

The table looks like

```
   id | upd | a1 | a2 .. | b1 | b2 | b3 |
   1  |     | 1  | 1     | 1  | 1  | 1  |
```

My query looks like:

```
UPDATE table t1, table t2 SET
    t1.b1  = GREATEST( 5, t1.a1),
    t1.upd = IF(t1.b1 <> t2.b1 ,1 , t1.upd)
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
```

Based on this query I would expect the table to look like this:

```
   id | upd | a1 | a2 .. | b1 | b2 | b3 |
   1  | 1*  | 1  | 1     | 5* | 1  | 1  |
*= updated
```

Only, it isn't. It executes the first line correctly (updating b1 to 5), but not the second one, setting the `upd` field.

The [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) states:

```
The second assignment in the following statement sets col2 to the current (updated) col1 value,
not the original col1 value. The result is that col1 and col2 have the same value.
 This behavior differs from standard SQL. 
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
```

So I would have expected the second line (update `upd`) to work as well.

If I add (as a test) these two lines

```
t1.b2=t1.b1,
t1.b3=t2.b1,
```

before the `t1.upd =` line, b2 and b3 still show `1`, where I expected b2 to be `5`.

Where am I going wrong in my logic (and understanding of MySQL :-)?

**NOTE** Sorry, I forget to mention: I connot use Triggers. Otherwis it would have been less difficult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this one:

```
UPDATE 
    table t1 
SET
    upd = 1, 
    b1 = GREATEST(5, a1) 
WHERE
    b1 <> GREATEST(5, a1) ;
```

No need for "copying" the table or using the (not 100% sure) assumption that MySQL updates the columns in a specific order.

The answers in your link are about a much more difficult to do (in MySQL) operation, i.e. swapping the values of 2 columns.

---

If you want to update multiple columns and set the `upd=1` column if at least one of the other columns is updated, you can use a simple `OR` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE 
    table t1 
SET
    upd = 1, 
    b1 = GREATEST(5, a1),
    b2 = GREATEST(7, a2),
    b3 = <whatever> 
    --- 
WHERE
   ( b1 <> GREATEST(5, a1)
  OR b2 <> GREATEST(7, a2)
  OR b3 <> <whatever> 
  ---
   ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. You are right about switching the columns, that works. As about your WHERE clause, in the end I want to add more b-colums to the `SET` instruction and update `upd` only once. The only solution I can come up with right now is adding `SET upd=IF(b1<>GREATEST(5, a1) OR b2<>GREATEST(5, a1)),1,upd)` before `SET b1= ....`. Limiting it to only one table, this seems to work. It would have been much simpler to have the old values in stead of recalculating the `GREATEST` every time, but that is impossible I think.

Answer (score 1):

Immediately following the text you quoted from the MySQL manual is this ([MySQL 5.7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)):

> Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order.

A more appropriate solution to your original issue of updating a column based on the existing value of another column would be an [AFTER UPDATE trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html). You can access the original value of a column using OLD, e.g. `OLD.b1`.

Comment: Just noticed that OP linked to the 5.0 manual, triggers are supported in MySQL 5.0.2 and later so hopefully this is still applicable.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention: I connot use Triggers. Otherwis it would have been less difficult